# SAPUI5 How to change Select item background-collor correctly?

Tags: css, select, sapui5, background-color

What is the best way to change background-color of select item? I see only one way - change some of basic classes (like sapMSelectListItem) but i am not sure if it's a correct way. I mean in future class which i will change can be changed too (i mean developers will change it's name).

Comment: never change a class directly, if you want to change css, assign a custom css class to your control and modify it by refering to the custom css class combined with possibly the sap class. e.g. `class= "customClass sapMSelectListItem"` and in your css you define the styling by `.customClass .sapMSelectListItem { ... }`

Comment: If you need that behavior in all apps, use Fiori Theme Designer